# events.js :174 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event when using expo

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-native, expo

I have setup my react native project using expo on android.

After 'expo start' it runs the application first time but after some time I am getting this error:

> events.js :174
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>         ^
>
> Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat
>   'D:\job_finder_with_authentication\node_modules.staging\set-blocking-ff60c335\LICENSE.txt'
>   Emitted 'error' event at:
>       at NodeWatcher. (D:\job_finder_with_authentication\node_modules\sane\src\node_watcher.js:291:16)
>       at callback (D:\job_finder_with_authentication\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:295:20)
>       at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:153:21)`

can someone please help me on this. My app is running directly from phone.

Answer (score 1):

Run `cd android && gradlew clean`

Answer (score 0):

- Open the Command Prompt as Administrator.
- Run expo start.